# Manipulate a parameter of the type Range in a function (VBA - excel)

Tags: excel, vba, function, range

I'm new to VBA and am having some problems, especially with the syntax.

I'm trying to do a function that counts how many repeated cells I have in a passing range (for now, I assume that should pass only a range with 1 column).

I have the following:

```
Public Function countRepeated(ByVal pRange As range) As Integer
Dim numberOfRows As Integer
Dim numberOfColumns As Integer
Dim repeated As Integer
Dim localRange As range

Set localRange = pRange

numberOfRows = localRange.Rows.Count
numberOfColumns = localRange.columns.Count

If (numberOfColumns > 1) Then
    temp = MsgBox("Insira intervalos com apenas 1 coluna.", vbExclamation, "Erro")
    countRepeated = -1
    Exit Function
End If

repeated = 0

For i = 1 To numberOfRows
    temporary = localRange.Cells(i, 1).Value
    For j = i + 1 To numberOfRows
        If (temporary = localRange.Cells(j, 1).Value And temporary <> "") Then
            repeated = repeated + 1
            localRange.Cells(j, 1).Value = ""
            'after the previous instruction, i get thet #VALUE! error
            'i also try set localRange.Cells(j,1).Value = ""
            'and localRange.Cells(j, 1).Value = 0
        End If
    Next j

Next i

countRepeated = repeated

End Function
```

But I am getting a `#VALUE!` error after I try to change a value from the Range. Initially I tried to modify the parameter itself (pRange), by passing it 'ByVal', but I get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are calling this function from a formula in a cell Excel will not allow you to change the value of another cell from inside the function.

Using `Set localRange=pRange`does not create a copy of pRange that you can manipulate.

Probably what you should do is to get pRange into a variant array and manipulate that:

```
dim localRange as variant
localRange=pRange.value2
```

then instead of `localRange.Cells(j,1)` use `localRange(j,1)`

Comment: Thanks Charles, that was exactly the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I can tell you about your code:

1. Your problem is here:

   `localRange.Cells(j, 1).Value = ""`

The value cannot be "". Try with `localRange.Cells(j, 1).Text = ""`

2. Do not use integers in VBA. 
   [Why Use Integer Instead of Long?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26409117/why-use-integer-instead-of-long)
3. If you are not able to rewrite your code with punkt 1, then give some example of input and output, and the people in StackOverflow will give you ideas.

That's all :) Cheers!